# How can I get a massive text file into a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I'm using [a list of words with positive and negative sentiment from AFINN](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/publication_details.php?id=6010) to do some text analysis.

Problem is, the list comes in a .txt file in the following format (word on the left, pos vs neg index at right):

```
casualty    -2
catastrophe -3
catastrophic    -4
cautious    -1
celebrate   3
celebrated  3
celebrates  3
celebrating 3
```

To work with it, I need it in the following format:

```
var array = [{word:"casualty",score:-2},{word:"catastrophe",score:-3},{word:"catastrophic",score:-4}, etc etc]
```

I'd actually prefer to do this once with a shell script, rather than in the browser. Which is why I'm thinking Node.js could come in handy here. But I'm not very familiar with Node.

[Direct link to the zip containing the raw text files.](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/6010/zip/imm6010.zip)

Comment: https://www.npmjs.org/package/csvtojson

Comment: You just need to convert the list once, to JSON, and then just include the file and parse it in javascript. If you know any serverside language, like PHP, it would be trivial to get the file, split on newlines, then split on spaces or tabs (whatever the separator is) and create arrays that match your outcome, json_encode the arrays, store to file etc.

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't really care about how to read text into a javascript array, and you just need AFINN in JSON, I just found a version [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thisandagain/sentiment/master/build/AFINN.json).